# importing cypher script using browser interface

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to import a Cypher script file using the browser interface.

I get the following error :

```
Invalid input 'b': expected <init> (line 1, column 1)
"begin"
^
```

The script file is something like :

```
// Create state node 
begin
CREATE (node {a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"})
commit
```

Is this format correct ? I can't seem to find much information on this topic

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to import is for the neo4j-shell.

You can access it in the command line by running the `./bin/neo4j-shell` command and pasting the content in it once the shell session started.

You can access it through the browser also, just point your local url to **localhost:7474/webadmin** instead of /browser

Then you can click on **"Powertool Console"** which is a web embedded version of the command line neo4j shell and you can then paste your file content in it.

Comment: so I don't need the begin/commit ?

Comment: Yes you do need it in the shell

Comment: and you don't need it in the browser

Comment: Certain "queries" don't seem to work with this approach (which work on the command line) ...  'MATCH (t),(c)
WHERE t.desc = 'xxx' AND c.desc = 'Tyyy'
CREATE (t)-[r:S{}]->(c) ' gives error WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

Comment: I was not thinking the shell and the browser would behave different except for the begin/commit. Can you post the whole query, here it does not seem to have a match after a create ?

Comment: Do you have something following that create statement? The statement alone should work fine without WITH.